# _clone() got an unexpected keyword argument 'klass' Django

Tags: python, django

I've tried to overwrite get_queryset method in order to customise count method but when I'm trying to call it I'm receiving a typo: "TypeError: _clone() got an unexpected keyword argument 'klass", I ve google it a little bit but I didn't find anything relatable.

admin.py:

```
 def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyAdminModel, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs._clone(klass=FastCountQuerySet)
```

Any thoughts on this topic? Thx in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to use the `_clone` method of the queryset? That's an internal API and you shouldn't be needing to use it.

Comment: also its hangs when I try to change class externally then clone without parameter.
any solution?

Comment: ever figure this out?